# Rails active record query for search filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-postgresql

Looking at the railscasts.com, I am wondering how Ryan implemented the search filters for the site. If the search param does not match anything in the database, then he is returning ALL records (for example, if we type an invalid param for the search param value in the URL, all records are returned because there is nothing to filter on). If it matches records in the database he is returning only those matching records.

How is being achieved? Can I use only Active Record without any gems/full-text-search for this? How would that query look like with Arel?

Also, how does he implement the filters link (links at the top of the page after we do a search)? Is he parsing through each of the search params and generating the links on the page by stripping out the search params one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see Railscasts.com is showing all records when invalid filters (like search parameters). When no record is found, it is returning a link to see all episodes. For example, see this link:
http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=
It says:

> No episodes found. See all episodes.

However, you can show all records in such cases if you want. it's very easy.

```
  def index
    @records = []
    if params[:search].present?
      #YOUR SEARCH LOGIC and assign to @records. for example:
      @records = Episode.where(:title => params[:search])
    end

    unless @records.length
      @records = Episode.all  
    end
  end
```

Comment: Check this out (filtering on an invalid "type") - http://railscasts.com/?type=AAAACCCCCDDDDD. Is there a way to do it in a single query?

Comment: Also, how is the filter being ignored, if the tag_id param is wrong? So he is able to determine that the tag_id param is obviously wrong (it should be an integer) and ignore creating a filter link on the search page. For example, see this (replace tag_id with an integer for comparison) - http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=r&type=nbcaaaaaa

Comment: ah, i see it now. is there any reason that you've to do it in single query? i don't see a way tough with instant thinking. if you want to check whether the filter is valid or invalid, you have to query your model to check if anything exists with that type_id. There is probably another model for that. So when you see that model does not return anything, you can consider it as wrong and query your actual episode for all records.

Comment: I am wondering if there is something we could construct that will say - "give me this if it exists in the database, otherwise, give me everything for that param". It should have been in one query because the tag_id is being ignored if it is invalid. I wouldn't imagine Ryan, first hitting the database to see if the tag_id exists, then if it doesn't exist (or is invalid), hitting the DB again with the rest of the params, and if those don't return anything, hit the DB again for ALL records. That sort of seems very inefficient

Comment: no, you don't have to do that. if you model correctly, your joined query will not produce results. in that case you have to query all which can be cached easily. querying is database is not inefficient when needed. it may be inefficient with complex queries that may not be re-used. sometime multiple queries is quicker than single complex join. you need to profile for that.